# webkit wont transform

Tags: css, visual-web-developer

When i use transform it works on every browser except for chrome and safari. It works on everything else. I posted the section i need help on. Thanks!

```
#top-nav{
background: #94b3c8;
text-align: cemter;
}

#top-nav dt {
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 30px;
font: 20px Tahoma;
color: white;
padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#top-nav a:active{
color: white;
text-decoration: underline;
}

#top-nav a:link{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

#top-nav a:visited{
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}

#top-nav a:hover{
color: white;
text-decoration: underline;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
-ms-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
-moz-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
-o-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

the nav Html. I don't think that this is the problem. (although it could have to do with using dl instead of ul):

```
<nav id='top-nav'>
            <dl>
                <dt> <a href='index.html'> Home </a></dt>
                <dt> <a href='FAQ.html'> FAQ </a> </dt>
                <dt> <a href='contact.html'> Contact </a></dt>
            </dl>
        </nav>
```

Comment: please include your HTML as well

Comment: needs to be a block element (display:block) rather than an inline element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to `#top-nav a:link{`

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/QaYx7/1/